# Como faco p ignorar um \ no codigo em Python

Tags: python

```
.download('C:\Users\Guilherme\Downloads')
```

Usei o Pytube e para fazer o download nessa pasta eu preciso de '', alguem sabe como eu posso ignorar p funcionar normalmente?

Comment: `.download('C:\\Users\\Guilherme\\Downloads')`?, [\[ref\]](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

Answer (score -3):

Poderia utilizar o valor `r` no inicio da string, para indicar ao compilador que é uma string `raw`. Desta forma não é necessário fazer o `escaping` da string. O resultado final ficaria assim:

```
.download(r'C:\Users\Guilherme\Downloads')
```

Veja o resultado de uma execução:

```
 a = r'C:\Users\Guilherme\Downloads'
 a
 # 'C:\\Users\\Guilherme\\Downloads'
```

Comment: Interessante burlar o bloqueio da pergunta fechada (duplicada, ainda por cima)...

Comment: eu tava no meio da escrita quando fecharam. :-)

Comment: Olá Danizavtz. Apenas como orientação, pois sua postagem foi sinalizada, devo lhe orientar que pesquise no site com calma antes de responder, perguntas mais simples assim provavelmente já possuem resposta(s) e nesse caso o ideal é votar para fechar como duplicata, isso quando a pergunta é clara e boa (bem elaborada), parece ser o caso dessa, então vote para fechar como duplicata, lembre-se dups podem coexistir, desde que a dup seja algo que ajude os usuários a pesquisarem e portanto evite de responder o que provavelmente já tem respostas.

Comment: para perguntas mal elaboradas escolha outro tipo de fechamento, que pode variar, recomendo que leia as dicas do [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/3635)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento entendo que tenha sido sinalizada, mas eu posso transformar em uma resposta de boa qualidade.

Comment: @Danizavtz não fui eu quem sinalizou, eu disse que sua postagem foi sinalizada, nem sempre é uma pessoa que sinaliza, no caso da sua foi o proprio sistema que indicou problema aparente (o que pode ser ou não verdade, por isso que o sistema só me sugere), mas não vou entrar em detalhes. Eu também não falei de resposta de baixa qualidade, a orientação aqui é sobre perguntas dups. Recomendo ler com calma o link, e seguir a orientação que já lhe passei. Se a orientação que passei não ficou clara pode abrir um questionamento no [META](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/). Obrigado por compreender.

Comment: Quando assim responda a pergunta marcada.

Comment: PS: Me falaram uma vez quando comecei no site, Para responder pergunta fechada tem que ser muito criterioso, pois a não ser que jogue um [lifeboat](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/334/lifeboat) não faça.